# How to use transparency in SoMaterial node to achieve a semi transparent effect

Tags: c++, openinventor, coin3d

Now I have a SoMaterial node, and I have set some of its properties as follows:

```
holderMaterial ->ambientColor. setValue (color [0]/255. f, color [1]/255. f, color [2]/255. f);
HolderMaterial ->diffuseColor. setValue (color [0]/255.0f, color [1]/255.0f, color [2]/255.0f);
HolderMaterial ->shinness=0.0;
HolderMaterial ->transparency=1- color [3]/255.0f;
```

But I found that once it becomes semi transparent, the color cannot be displayed on a white background. What is the solution

I use this vector color[4] = { 230, 178, 133, 254 }
and just as the picture shown , it has no color on a white background

[[black background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHyNA.png)]

[[white background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA3z8.png)]

I hope it maintains the same visual effect on different background colors, preferably on a black background

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work correctly with my version of Open Inventor.
Can you provide a small test case that reproduces the problem?

Neither of the images you provided seem correct. :)  In the black background image you have some light-blue geometry, but the color values you are using should produce more of a "tan" color.

One thing to check is the transparency type you are telling Open Inventor to use. Depending on the order of objects in the scene graph, the default transparency type may not produce the correct image for some camera orientations.

Comment: I checked the transparency type and found that if it is ADD, it will be affected by the background. Using BLEND can obtain the correct color. Thank you for your suggestion！
But in order to solve the problem caused by semi transparency, I need to create a new scene to handle it separately, because directly modifying to BLEND will have an impact on my other opaque objects. Is there a good solution?